# Не получается подключить динамическую библиотеку в CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Пытаюсь подключить самописную динамическую библиотеку в другой проект,однако подключение не удаётся:вылетает ошибка.Cама библиотека представляет из себя одну функцию `int* DSort(int* a,int size)`, сортирующая массив.Операционная система `Ubuntu`. Библиотека скорее всего создана правильно,так-как ее создание происходило по средствам среды разработки (CLion). Ниже привожу код CMake в  папке `cmake` (файл `FindBubbleSort.cmake`) проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
set(FIND_DBUBBLESORT_PATHS
    /home/denis/Libraries/DBubbleSort
    )

find_path(DDBUBBLESORT_INCLUDE_DIR DSort.h   
    PATH_SUFFIXES include               
    PATHS ${FIND_DBUBBLESORT_PATHS})

find_library(DBUBBLESORT_LIBRARY               
    NAMES libuntitled7.so                      
    PATH_SUFFIXES lib
```

И в файле CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(UserOFDynamicSort)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

add_executable(UserOFDynamicSort main.cpp)

include(FindPkgConfig)
find_package(DBubbleSort REQUIRED)
include_directories(${DBUBBLESORT_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DBUBBLESORT_LIBRARY})
```

Код приложения,пытающийся получить доступ к библиотеке:

```
int a [10] = {1,2,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9};
Dsort(a,10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d",a[i]);
```

Код DSort.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" int* Dsort(int a[], int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size-1;j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }return a;
}
```

Код DSort.h:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED7_LIBRARY_H
#define UNTITLED7_LIBRARY_H

int* Dsort(int a[],int size);

#endif
```

И ошибка:

> CMakeFiles/UserOFDynamicSort.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
>   /home/denis/CLionProjects/UserOFDynamicSort/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to`Dsort(int*, int)'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> CMakeFiles/UserOFDynamicSort.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target
>
> 'UserOFDynamicSort' failed
>   make[3]: *** [UserOFDynamicSort] Error 1
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target
>
> 'CMakeFiles/UserOFDynamicSort.dir/all' failed
>
> make[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpPGD.png): *** [CMakeFiles/UserOFDynamicSort.dir/all] Error 2
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/UserOFDynamicSort.dir/rule' failed
>
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/UserOFDynamicSort.dir/rule] Error 2
>
> Makefile:118: recipe for target 'UserOFDynamicSort' failed
>
> make: *** [UserOFDynamicSort] Error 2

Comment: В CLion отсутствуют средства для создания библиотек, все делается через cmake.

Comment: Для новых версий это не так:при создании проекта есть возможность создать библиотеку

Comment: Ну вот у Вы приводите код с командой, имя который начинается с `find`. Эта команда  _ищет_ файлы. Где код создания цели и линковки этой библиотеки? Находит ли библиотеку CMake (что содержится в `DYNAMIC_BUBBLESORT_LIBRARY`)?

Comment: @ixSci спасибо,дополнил описание по Вашей рекомендации

Comment: Что такое `DBUBBLESORT_LIBRARY`? Почему Вы ищите библиотеку в переменную `DYNAMIC_BUBBLESORT_LIBRARY`, а при линковке используете что-то другое? В общем, Вы явно не понимаете как всё это работает, а с теми крупицами информации, Вам помочь очень сложно. Поэтому придётся разбираться самостоятельно.

Comment: @ixSci, да,извиняюсь,в процессе попыток исправления кода насоздавал кучу проектов и перепутал переменные,ошибку исправил,если еще актуально

Comment: Там надо разбираться, выводить значения переменных, смотреть что в них содержится и т.п. Судя по всему у Вас библиотека не находится. Причины могут быть разные.

Comment: @ixSci спасибо,буду копать в этом направлении